# DocumentFormat.OpenXML dll refernece in VS project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, dll, openxml

I am trying to include DocumentFormat.OpenXML dll into my project. I have installed OpenXML SDK(It's 32 bit, Couldn't find a version specifically for 64 bit system). I added the dll to the references of the project. It still says: `The type or namespace name 'DocumentFormat' could not be found.` What is the problem here? I tried re-adding dll and restarted VS, but with no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no version specific for a 64 bit system, have you added DocumentFormat and WindowsBase references, because the OpenXML sdk depends on the WindowsBase dll to work. Make sure both have been added.